# How to install Stencil-CLI for BigCommerce properly

Tags: javascript, node-modules, bigcommerce

I want to install Stencil-CLI for BigCommerce and got this error list:

[image]

`Command failed: git submodule update -q --init --recursive`

I'm using node version 12.22.9 (I've also tried version 22.7 and 22.8, but the issue was present there too); nvm version is 0.36.0.

Reinstalling nvm and/or node didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, just wait for response from git repo, and then it will fix itself (I just went home, and the next day I just ran this command again)